# Grouping records by pairs SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this, which should describe roomate's pair.

```
    name| surname | city      | distance|sex | roomate
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Mike|  Tyson  | London    | 599     | M  | Oliver Red
    -----------------------------------------------------       
    Ron | Simpson | Newcastle | 4       | M  | John Godson
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Tim | Black   | Dover     | 311     | M  | 
    -----------------------------------------------------
    John| Godson  | Calais    | 111     | M  | Ron Simpson
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Oliver| Red   | Dover     | 99      | M  | Mike Tyson
```

Is it possible to order it like pairs and the distance columm like above? If not, is it possible to order data like pairs? It is more important ;)

```
    name  | surname |   city    | distance|sex | roomate
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Mike  |  Tyson  | London    | 599     | M  | Oliver Red
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Oliver| Red     | Dover     | 99      | M  | Mike Tyson
    -----------------------------------------------------
    John  | Godson  | Calais    | 111     | M  | Ron Simpson
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Ron   | Simpson | Newcastle | 4       | M  | John Godson
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Tim   | Black   | Dover     | 311     | M  | 
    -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: whats your definition for pairs? what says they need to be paired together?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can order your results by column names. (e.g. distance, roomate).

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY distance, roommate;
```

Comment: but in such way roomate won't be in the pair!

Comment: SELECT name, surname, city, distance FROM table ORDER BY distance. Or roommate should be moved to a different table.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is to conditionally order your rows... meaning you need to know the number of rows... **I would recommend changing your table to include a room number** or something like that so that you can order by that..

here is a sample query showing a conditional sort.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            roomate = 'Oliver Red' 
         OR CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) = 'Oliver Red'
        THEN 1
        WHEN 
            roomate = 'Ron Simpson' 
         OR CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) = 'Ron Simpson'
        THEN 2
        ELSE 5
    END,
    distance DESC;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89686/1)